# AS3: Sound class not working on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, audio

I'm trying to use some sound effect for my as3 game. When i debug it on PC, everything works fine, but when I try debugging directly on my android device, no sound plays.
I'm using Sound class, with embed mp3 file. Does anyone have clue what might be wrong?

Comment: have you added user permissions on Android manifest ?

Comment: @Ramaraj which permission handles playing sound? i haven't found any.

Comment: @f-a `[Embed(source='collect.mp3')]                              public var collect:Class                                         public var sound:Sound;                                           sound = new collect();                                        sound.play();  ` Sorry I can't get it to format in lines :/